# Как в Angular создать массив изображений, которые хранятся в папке Assets?

Tags: angular2, typescript

Есть сайт с изображениями, при нажатии на миниатюру должна открываться картинка на весь экран. Как можно добавить изображения из папки Assets в массив используя Angular 8?
Мой class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nature',
  templateUrl: './nature.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nature.component.css']
})
export class NatureComponent implements OnInit {
  visib:boolean =true;

  constructor() { }
  scaleImage(){

    this.visib = !this.visib;

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Описание CSS:

```
.imj{
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  float:left;
  margin-top: 10%;

}
.imj img{
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 0.5%;

}

.visib{
  width: 70%;
  height: 60%;
 margin-left: 15%;
  background-image: url("mec.jpg");
  border:2px solid green;

}

.vist{
  width: 70%;
  height: 60%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  background-image: url("3.jpg");
  border:2px solid green;

}
```

Comment: @nörbörnën Зачем вы убрали метки? Я указал, что использую Angular 8 а вы ставите метку Angular2

Comment: под меткой [tag:angularjs] задаются вопросы про angular первой версии, вопросы про современный angular сгруппированы под метками [tag:angular] и [tag:angular2] и нет большого смысла уточнять его версию. остальные метки, связанные с массивами, не несли особого смысла так как ответ будет связан, скорее всего, не с массивами, а с тем как с помощью webpack на этапе сборки считать содержимое каталога и пробросить в компонент

Comment: Причем тут webpack? я его не использую в данном проекте. Я новичок в веб разработке, не могли бы Вы мне помочь с данной проблемой?

Comment: я, к сожалению, умею angularjs и лишь поверхностно знаком с angular. могу рассказать очень примерно. у вас есть 2 варианта решить задачу: 1) в компоненте завести список картинок, просто перечислить пути к картинкам от того места, которое сборщик считает корнем проекта (возможно это потребует доконфигурации сборщика) и 2) научить сборщика читать содержимое каталога и подставлять в этот компонент.

Comment: а вообще, я думаю, лучше подождать ответы тех, кто знает angular лучше чем я

Comment: @RubikVarosyan а что именно вызвало у тебя трудность создать массив, который состоит из путей к изображениями в папке assets?

Comment: Я знаю, как создать массив строк, или цифр, но не знаю как создать массив, в котором я могу указать расположение папки, изображения, в которой должны являться элементами массива. Не понимаю как синтаксически это должно выглядеть

Comment: @RubikVarosyan, имена файлов известны? Или имена не известны и вы хотите каком то образом "прочитать" их?